# JavaScript / Angular copy one property of objects in an array to another objects array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, initialization

So basically, I have two arrays : `donnees: IDonnee[]` and `donneesApfTrackingBoard: IDonneeBoard[]`

Here are the two interfaces :

```js
export interface IDonnee {
entity: string;
description: string;
}
```

```js
export interface IDonneeApfTrackingBoard {
entity: string;
position: string;
date: string;
```

And basically what I have is objects in the array "donnees", and they all have an entity. What I want to do is **optimally initializing objects in the second array so I can do use this code :**

```js
    this.donneesApfTrackingBoard = new Array(this.donnees.length).fill({});
for (i = 0; i < this.donnees.length; i++) {
  this.donneesApfTrackingBoard[i].entity = this.donnees[i].entity;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you've posted not work?

Comment: my question is how to i initialize the objects in the array "donneesBoard" because if they're not initialized I think I can't assign the `this.donnees[i].entity`

I get the following error : Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Just sett `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard = []` before your `for` loop, and `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard[i].push({})` before you set each entity

Comment: you can also try `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard  = this.donnees.map((element)=>element['entity])`

Comment: you said `donneesApfTrackingBoard: IDonneeBoard`, so `donneesApfTrackingBoard` is not an array. Thus `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard[0]` will always return `undefined`.

Comment: I've tried these solutions but I can't make it work =/
@pandamakes oops yes it's `IDonneeBoard[]` in the code but since the IDonneeBoard[0] for example is not initialized i can't put the value inside IDonneeBoard[0].entity

Comment: I suppose you can use: `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard = new Array(this.donnees.length).fill({})` before the for loop?

Comment: yes now theres no error thanks ! but with my original code, `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard` is filled only with the last value of the entity of `this.donnees` which means every entity of `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard` is equal to this.donnees[this.donnees.length].entity's value, any idea of why?

Comment: and if i do `this.donneesApfTrackingBoard[0].businessUnit = 'hi';` then everything entities will be equal to "hi"